# Retrieving data from json and a url

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a question, what can I do to get specific data back and send to my channel when I type `!test`?
Normally, when I issue a request to this URL I get the following response:

```
http://192.168.1.12/JSON?request=getstatus&ref=4030
```

```
{"Name":"HomeSeer Devices","Version":"1.0","Devices":[{"ref":4030,"name":"ttt","location":"ttt","location2":"ttt","value":0,"status":"Off","device_type_string":"AC Input Device Unknown Sensor","last_change":"\/Date(1548247933316)\/","relationship":0,"hide_from_view":false,"associated_devices":[],"device_type":{"Device_API":4,"Device_API_Description":"Plug-In API","Device_Type":73,"Device_Type_Description":"Plug-In Type 73","Device_SubType":97,"Device_SubType_Description":"AC[16B5BB2-10]a\u0002y\u0002\u00020\u00020\u00020\u00020\u00020\u00020\u0002n\u00021\u00020"},"device_image":"","UserNote":"","UserAccess":"Any","status_image":"/images/HomeSeer/status/off.gif","voice_command":"tttt","misc":4864}]}
```

I want the bot to reply with that status every time I execute the `!test` command.
How can I do that?

Next question: how can I set it to send the request with the `value` parameter?

```
http://192.168.1.12/JSON?request=controldevicebyvalue&ref=4030&value=0
```

I want that if I type `!Device 0` it sets `value` to 0 by issuing that request.

This is how I'm handling commands:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  // If the message is "ping"
  if (message.content === '!ping') {
 // Send "pong" to the same channel
    message.channel.send('pong');
  }
});
```

Comment: Please research and try first before creating a question so others will do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package from npm. You can use the command below to install it:

[image: npm package]

To use it you first need to require it, then simply put the URL you want to request to: the result will be passed to the callback:

```
const request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
```

In your case, I would do it like this:

````
client.on('message', message => {
  // Detect the command
  if (message.content.startsWith('!status')) {
    // Issue the request
    request('http://192.168.1.12/JSON?request=getstatus&ref=4030', (error, response, body) => {
      // If there has been an error, log it
      if (error) console.error(error);
      // Otherwise, you can reply with the JSON you got back
      else message.channel.send("```json\n" + body + "\n```");
    });
  }
});
````

If you want to turn that `body` string into an object, you'll need to [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it.

```
request('http://192.168.1.12/JSON?request=getstatus&ref=4030', (error, response, body) => {
  let object = JSON.parse(body);
  // Once you have the object you can get all of its properties like you'd normally do
});
```

Your second problem can be solved in the same way: you just need to set thonURL depending of the argument.
If you still haven't, you'll need to create an argument parser: there are a lot of ways to do that, I'll just show you the easiest one for this example:

````
client.on('message', message => {
  let args = message.content.split(' '), // Get the arguments
    command = args.shift(); // Let the first be the command
  // If there's no first argument, reply with this message
  if (!args[0]) return message.reply("Please enter a value.");

  if (command == '!device') {
    request('http://192.168.1.12/JSON?request=controldevicebyvalue&ref=4030&value=' + args[0], (error, response, body) => {
      // If there has been an error, log it
      if (error) console.error(error);
      // Otherwise, you can reply with the JSON you got back
      else message.channel.send("```json\n" + body + "\n```");
    });
  }
});
````

If you need the object from `body` for some reason, you can parse it as shown above.

Comment: You should also use `message.content.substring()` to parse the value and add it to the url.

Comment: @Tvde1 Can you show me how ? im learning java still.. regards and thankyou,

Comment: @Federico Grandi can you show me how to get STATUS only from my json link? i don't know how to use JSON.parse()

Comment: @user3785784 It is JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: Ok i did this but how to get the second data status because its after a {  `request('http://192.168.1.12/JSON?request=controldevicebyvalue&ref=4030&value=100', (error, response, body) => {
obj = JSON.parse(body);

console.log(obj.Devices);
});`

Comment: @FedericoGrandi  i did do what you said but i cant get the data after "Devices":[{ because its behind a { so how to get that ?  i did use the code bove my message. regards and thanks

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is: can you formulate the question better?

Comment: Its ok, i did find it out, i needed to get in the second array.

Comment: Happy to hear that! If my question solved your problem, please accept it by clicking on the tick symbol on the left: this will mark your question as solved :)

Comment: @FedericoGrandi i did do that now :) many thanks for your help. But can you look at my other question.. i'm really stuck. its on the other page  regards

Answer (score -1):

Try installing and importing the opn module:
 Command Line: `$ npm install opn`
 Then install it into your code: `const opn = require('opn')`

Then something along the lines of

```
if (message.content == "!Device 0") {
    opn('http://192.168.1.12/JSON?request=controldevicebyvalue&ref=4030&value=0');
}
```

Comment: this does open a webpage on my server and if i do multiple requests the windows wil stay open.. is there an other way to do this in the background.

Comment: Hmm...maybe the ``os`` module would have something? I don't really know, I'm just guessing around.

Comment: any idea how i can get the json data ? i have getJSON module and it returns the json string normal but when i use console.log(response.Devices) i get the seconds lines but i cant get in status.. how to do that ? see json string in my post